# usb autorun in windows 7 using with programming languages

Tags: usb, autorun

I want to execute(run) a program when the usb is connected on any system.
I don't know that What are methods(algorithms) to do it?
Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: I'm windows application programmer with vb6,c#

Comment: If it is possible answers in this regard

Answer (score 0):

on any system is difficult but on windows write any program (.exe) while you use VB6 and make autorun.inf file put it with your program in usb stick to make it up with connected.